# check and read file from subdomain

Tags: php, permissions, subdomain, file-exists

i have subdomain sub.domain.com. the subdomain points on a directory root/sub of my root dir on my Webserver.
now i have pdfs on another dir on the server root/pdf.
How can i check if a specific pdf exists and if it exists i want to copy the file to a temp dir of the subdomain.

if i call a php script sub/check.php an try to check a pdf that exists :

```
$filename = "http://www.domain.com/pdf/1.pdf";
if (file_exists($filename)) 
{
    "exists";
} 
else 
{
    "not exists";
}
```

It always shows : not exists.
If i take the url and put it in a browser - the pdf will be shown.

How can my php script in the /sub-folder access files in the root or root/pdf ?

bye jogi

Comment: Is your question answered by now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`file_exists()`** function does not work that way. It does not take remote URLs.

This function is used to check the file that exists on the file system.

Check the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

Make use of cURL to accomplish this.

```
    <?php
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png"); //pass your pdf here

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($retcode==200)
     {
      echo "exists";
     }
   else
     {
      echo "not exists";
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: ok, thanks so far. but how can i copy the file to my sub-dir ?

Comment: `system("cp http://www.domain.com/pdf/1.pdf http://www.domain.com/sub/temp/1.pdf")`

Comment: and   `system("cp ../pdf/1.pdf ./temp/1.pdf");`

Comment: @user1121575, That is not related to the question right ? Anyways you can look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843933/copy-file-from-remote-server-or-url

Comment: i thought it is possible to use curl for both ways. i want to check and read the file - so i thought it is related to the question

Answer (score 0):

file_exists() looks locally on the machine if a file exists. But what you are doing is using a URL.

Since you say your script is in the root folder, you need to do change

```
$filename = "http://www.domain.com/pdf/1.pdf";
```

into

```
$filename = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/pdf/1.pdf"; // first part gets current directory
```

Comment: my script is not in the root folder. it is in the /sub - folder

Comment: @user1121575 Ok, then do: `$filename = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/../pdf/1.pdf";` The .. will take you one directory back.