# getting file information via url in php

Tags: php

like file upload there are

```
<?php
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$_FILES['file']['name'];
$_FILES['file']['size'];
$_FILES['file']['type'];
?>
```

now.
i have a file that is sitting on my other web server, and i want to get the name size and mime type of that file via url.. is this possible?..

i've alreay tried to use this code below. but it doesn't work

```
    $url = "http://mydomain.com/myfile.rar";
    filesize ( $url );
    mime_content_type ( $url );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy file from remote server or URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843933/copy-file-from-remote-server-or-url)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781876/get-file-content-via-php-curl

Answer (score 6):

You can try native php function [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) it's very fast way to read file data

Comment: hahaha.. thanks for this i've already forget to use get_headers function.

Comment: Mark my answer pleezzz

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like this. The information you get when you use $_FILES is meta-information that is sent along with the file (and the size can even be calculated after the file is retrieved).

You cannot get this information like that, but you *can* download the actual file and inspect the header information to get that information. To do this, [read about curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), which allows you to do HTTP requests to another server.

It might be possible to [request just the headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php), so you get the information without getting the file, which is obviously more efficient.

Another solution is to implement a file-info script on the other server that allows you to get the file info. 
So you could request `http://mydomain.com/fileinfo.php?file=myfile.rar`. In fileinfo.php you can get all the file info of the given file and just echo it.