# HOW I can transfer files from one server to another server without web forms?

Tags: php, server

How to transfer file from one server to another server in php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Does this need to be a one time transfer or ongoing

Comment: @Kazz Can I transfer file using curl?
I think I transfer files using curl

Comment: I imagine you could do it with FTP, thought i have not got through it thuroughly: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using CURL You can transfer files from one server to another server.

**Here is example :**

**Uploading file**

```
<?php

/* http://localhost/upload.php: print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES); */

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array(‘name’ => ‘Foo’, ‘file’ => ‘@/home/user/test.png’);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ‘http://localhost/upload.php&#8217;);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch); ?>
```

Comment: Sir the above code is to transfer the file.how can i fetch and insert the file to folder on the other side ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
$remote_file_url = 'http://some--url/file.zip';

/* New file name and path  */
$local_file = 'file.zip';

/* Copy the file from source url to server */
$copy = copy( $remote_file_url, $local_file );

/* Add notice for success/failure */
if( !$copy ) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
else{
    echo " success to copy $file...\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you try this code anywhere?
and thank for your suggestion. :)

Comment: You can check first accepted answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843933/copy-file-from-remote-server-or-url)

Comment: yes I have check but using curl is easy for transfer file without web forms,
so i use curl

Comment: Glad to hear you found what youre looking for ; )